# Troubling displaying bitmap background using libnds

Tags: c, thumb, nintendo-ds, libnds

I'm having some issues getting a 16-bit (ARGB, 1-bit alpha, 5-bit colour channel) bitmap image which I converted using GRIT to display.

I have the following image, [`smpte_colour_bars.png`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os6RD.png). I converted it with GRIT using the following command line: `grit smpte_colour_bars.png -gb -gB16 -fts -osmpte_colour_bars` which gives me an *.s file for assembling into an object and a *.h header file for including in my project so I can reference the data.

However, when I use it in [my project's code](https://gist.github.com/twokilohertz/1ca7f593c733cfd55495359b49e23a86), all I get is a black screen: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DQjn.png).

I've looked through the relevant examples & documentation and I cannot track down the issue. Using DeSmuME's memory view, I can see that the data is being correctly written to memory & the tile view [reflects that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrJx8.png).

I have tested my code on two different emulators and real hardware and the problem is the same across all of them. Any insight into what might be going wrong would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple fix in the end after working out what was wrong. It turns out you must specify `-gT!` to explicitly disable transparency in the resulting bitmap otherwise the background is essentially see-through.